# Software-shredding a disk with bad sectors

Tags: command-line, disk, drive, shredding

I have my own company and when I take some hardware from customers, I always offer to shred the data on their drives and drill holes if not possible (in general for free, to get hardware for repairs etc.).

Some of these have bad sectors and this kind of stops/block the shredding.

I'm have two Ubuntu Server computers, which I plug in drives to shred in (you just don't do that on the computer you're actively using).

So I'm wondering if there's some good **CLI tool, to shred data on disks with bad sectors**, or if you short could repair the disk before and then shred it, with an application which then take the bad sectors into account.

*I also drill holes into the drives, however it sounds better and more professional if I say that I first shred the data and then drill the holes (just that I also need to shred the data otherwise I would be lying).*

*In the past, if I was playing cheapstake, then I could in Windows, format a drive or do write tests to the drive and see where it got stuck and create a partition before and after the bad sectors, but this would be tedious to do, especially at where bad drives.
I'm not that good with Xnix/Ubuntu, I sort of use it for learning, shredding and on older/slower computers (in short, you have been warned!).*

Comment: Related:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229354/how-to-ignore-write-errors-while-zeroing-a-disk  But, through experience of using an application like HDDRegenerator, bad sectors can be recovered a lot.  Not saying that all bad sectors can, but I have had great success in the past recovering data with the application I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I stumbled on that question/link/topic, before but got lost in it.

I'll take a note HDDRegenerator, it might come in handy at one point (already bought quite a few products from EaseUS, it will have to be enough on that spending for a while).

I'm trying this command now: sudo dd iflag=fullblock oflag=direct conv=noerror,notrunc if=/dev/zero of=/dev/Target_Disk status=progress

But it doesn't go above 30% CPU usage of a one core, so I'll have to figure out how I can speed it up. When I used Scrub, but with random setting, it ate a full core. But I'll ask in the link you sent.

Comment: sudo dd iflag=fullblock oflag=direct conv=noerror,notrunc if=/dev/zero of=/dev/Target_Disk status=progress bs=131 072


bs= sets write speed and must be in blocks that doubles
Default is 512, that's around 6 MB/s


bs=32768
126 MB/s

bs=131 072
Started at 145 MB/s, but went down to 127 MB/s.

You could likely double the last value to 262144, as it won't go above what it can write to the disk, but will attempt to use more speed when it can.
The funny part is that DD currently use only use 10-12% of one core, scrub, but with random instead of zero, used 100% of one core.

Comment: Please add to your question if you are talking about HDD (spinning) or SSD (flash memory). This makes a BIG difference. I assume HDD, but we need to be sure.
Additionally some vendors provide tools for low-level handling of HDDs. Might be helpful to know the vendor of the device (add this info to question).
Did you have a look on `hdparm` tool?

Comment: @Marco
HDD, not a specific vendor (I shred several drives at times). SSD is of interest too. Haven't tried hdparm yet.

I went to the link in the first comment and got some answer there, the DD command with some modification did the trick I believe.

This will cover my own drives and some customer drives which have been waiting.

I'm also going to try this:
sdd -inull bs=1m of=/dev/rdsk/cXdXtXp0 -noerror

And this with hdparm:
https://tinyapps.org/docs/wipe_drives_hdparm.html

The issue when it comes to CLI, is that you rarely find enough information as a new user.